# VBA Macro to read JSON

Tags: json, vba, excel

Hi I need to read the below **JSON** using a **VBA Macro**. Please help me to solve this. I want to read the below **JSON** and export it to excel format.

```
{"results":[{"series":[{"name":"Data","columns":["time","AggregationType","AggregationValue"],"values":[["2017-05-07T05:30:00Z","Avg",1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a JSON parser tool for VBA such as the excellent [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON). Their README documentation has great examples for how to read JSON data and output to a worksheet.